# Page up/down with smooth scrolling?

Tags: macos, keyboard, mouse, trackpad

When scrolling a page up or down using <kbd>fn</kbd> <kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>fn</kbd> <kbd>↓</kbd> in a text editor, the editor jumps immediately to the next page. This is confusing when reading structured documents such as source code (programming). Is there a way to get OS X to smoothly scroll down one page, as if I would have used the trackpad?

Comment: Which text editor are you using?

Comment: I am using Eclipse. I dont really care about it being "smooth", just that I dont get thrown down an entire page each time I hit page down. I want it to scroll as if I had done that using the mouse.

Comment: Keep in mind Eclipse is written in Java, which means it is not really a native Mac app, and therefore much less likely to have smooth scrolling. Even some diehard Mac apps (e.g. BBEdit, per below answer) do not scroll smoothly.

Answer (score 2):

Smooth scrolling is dependent on the application. TextEdit does offer smooth scrolling when paging through a long document. BBEdit 11 does not.

Apple's [developer WWDC 2013 talk below](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2013-215/) is aimed at helping developers to achieve this:

> #### [Optimizing Drawing and Scrolling on OS X](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2013-215/)
>
> Creating a responsive app requires fast drawing and smooth scrolling. Discover techniques to optimize drawing, find out best practices for handling layers, and learn how to combine those techniques with new features to achieve smooth scrolling.

If possible, provide feedback to the editor's developer that you value this behaviour.